# Get last part of url using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I get the last parameter of the URL using jQuery. For example in following URL I want to get 1.

```
localhost/x/y/page/1/
```

I'm trying following

```
var url = $(location).attr('href');
var parts = url.split("/");
var last_part = parts[parts.length-1];
alert(last_part);
```

It returns empty value.

Comment: That's because you're splitting the '/'. There's a / at the end. Try parts.length-2

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If the "/" is definitely at the end of your url, no matter what.. then just change:

```
var last_part = parts[parts.length-2]
```

(use 2 instead of 1) because of ncdreamy's comment.

Also, you don't need var var var var var... just var once and a comma separator:

```
var url = $(location).attr('href'),
    parts = url.split("/"),
    last_part = parts[parts.length-2];
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
hrefurl=$(location).attr("href");
last_part=hrefurl.substr(hrefurl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```

using jquery

```
$(location).attr("href").split('/').pop();
```

Comment: Have you checked? your jQuery solution doesnt seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/D2UjM/1/

Comment: Thats because fiddle href does not have last parameter in it.

Answer (score 5):

Very Simple Solution

```
let url = $(location).attr('href');
let urlKey = url.replace(/\/\s*$/, "").split('/').pop();
console.log(urlKey)
```

1. first get the url
2. Replace last `/` from the url
3. split with `/` and pop the last element

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to split via '/' so the last / is splitting the url as well. Try this:

```
var url = "localhost/x/y/page/1/";
var parts = url.split("/");
var last_part = parts[parts.length-2];
alert(last_part);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tEt62/

Answer (score 0):

Think this will help you.

Here index indicates the split point.

```
var str="url";

str.split("/")[3]
```

Comment: This will only work for specific URLs. The author asks for a generic solution.

Comment: @Simon - All right but he is new to SO don't please discourage him with -1.

Comment: @Code Monkey - Your answer is right but it is static think dynamically and answer it . Thanks

Comment: @sudharsan- Thanks for the support.I have to think in innovative way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to use jQuery. Just use `var last = window.location.pathname`

Comment: Doesn't that return `x/y/page/1/`?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know if there will be / at the end of url then use @relic solution like this:

```
var url =  $(location).attr('href').replace(/\/+$/,''), //rtrim `/`
    parts = url.split("/"),
    last_part = parts[parts.length-1];
```